# ckeditor4 CDN add extra plugin "templates"

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I know how to add an extra plugin to CKEditor CDN. But the problem is, the plugin "templates" is already loaded.

How can I change the templates of the "templates" plugin when the editor is loaded through the CDN?

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/templates